# Saving Microphone Stream to mp3 or wave

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, mp3, wav, microphone

I recording sound from Microphone in Windows Phone device. Using `Xna.Framework.Audio.Microphone` I store the sound in `MemoryStream`. I can save it to PCM format. However It will be much better to convert it to mp3 file. If converting to mp3 is impossible then maybe somebody at least knows how to convert it to wav.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I still have the same question. Lame, Ogg and WMA Encoders do not work on WP7. :-(

Answer (score 6):

Here is a brief example I created showing how to save wp7 recorded audio as a wav stream:
http://damianblog.com/2011/02/07/storing-wp7-recorded-audio-as-wav-format-streams/

Comment: do you have any idea of creating the wavstream as an mp3 file

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great thread which answers this question:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/59af6c3b-0dd1-4fa0-8438-d7f82e655109

> It is a simple WAV file with its
>   header missing. Therefore, Windows has
>   no clue about the format.
>   Unfortunately, the current WP7 OS API
>   (as far as I know) doesn't offer any
>   service to create a WAV file (the RIFF
>   header + the raw PCM data). The RIFF
>   header is not complicated and well
>   documented. It is fairly simple to
>   write the managed code to create one
>   using the known PCM format which, as
>   you already know, is 16bit/mono.

Or alternatively, if you're only trying to save/play it on the wp7 device ...

> You should be able to use;
>
> ```
>  SoundEffect sePlay = new SoundEffect(yourSavedByte[], mic.SampleRate, AudioChannels.Mono);
>  sePlay.Play();
> ```
>
> to playback your audio byte[]. I
>   record, save, and playback using just
>   the byte[] on WP7. You shouldn’t need
>   anything more then the raw byte[] if
>   you use the SoundEffect class for
>   playback.