# Is it possible to export a soundEffect as an audio file on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm writing an app that can record sounds as soundEffects from XNA. Is it possible to save those sound effects as say an MP3, WAV, or WMA file? I know with the Camera class in XNA, you can export the texture and image data as a jpg file, but is there a similar function with soundEffects? I know there's IsolatedStorage, but I need users to be able to plug their phone into the computer and be able to easily access their sound files and I'm pretty sure users have no access to the IsolatedStorge used by the app.

Comment: Are you using the microphone, or actually creating the sounds with the XNA framework?

Comment: I'm using the microphone to record the sounds and then store that into a SoundEffect using the XNA framework.

Comment: have you seen this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437921/saving-microphone-stream-to-mp3-or-wave) or [this](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+phone+save+microphone+mp3&go=Submit&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=windows+phone+save+microphone+mp3&sc=0-27&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=5991038d6c864d1fb854dd2a053c331c)?